# Restore Fixed Assets records with custom field and related table records

Tags: acumatica

In Fixed Assets (FA303000), I have customization that contains two custom fields and one custom table which is a child table referenced with FixedAsset's AssetID column.

Now, for some reason, we have to delete half of our fixed assets and put it back into Acumatica again. We are not creating the whole snapshot to create and restore the process. We are processing half of fixed assets records by removing it and put it back.

My initial thought was I just needed to put those records into some temporary table using (select * into duplicate_FixedAsset from FixedAsset.) then, delete those records from FixedAsset and put it back into FixedAsset.

Custom Fields record from Fixed Assets will be back, and for my custom child table that is linked via AssetID, I can use AssetCD to get AssetID and link it back again and everything should be fine.

But, I got wrong when inserting this record didn't appear back into the Fixed Assets page.

Upon inspecting Row_Deleting event, I found below code snippet.

```
protected virtual void FixedAsset_RowDeleting(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletingEventArgs e)
        {
            FixedAsset asset = (FixedAsset)e.Row;
            if (asset == null) return;

            if (null != (FATran)PXSelect<FATran, Where<FATran.assetID, Equal<Current<FixedAsset.assetID>>, And<FATran.batchNbr, IsNotNull>>>.SelectSingleBound(this, new object[] { asset }))
            {
                throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.BalanceRecordCannotBeDeleted);
            }

            this.EnsureCachePersistence(typeof(FARegister));
            this.EnsureCachePersistence(typeof(FABookHistory));

            foreach (FARegister reg in PXSelectJoinGroupBy<FARegister,
                LeftJoin<FATran, On<FARegister.refNbr, Equal<FATran.refNbr>>>,
                Where<FATran.assetID, Equal<Required<FixedAsset.assetID>>>,
                Aggregate<GroupBy<FARegister.refNbr>>>.Select(this, asset.AssetID))
            {
                this.Caches<FARegister>().Delete(reg);
            }

            foreach (FABookHistory hist in PXSelect<FABookHistory, Where<FABookHistory.assetID, Equal<Required<FixedAsset.assetID>>>>.Select(this, asset.AssetID))
            {
                this.Caches<FABookHistory>().Delete(hist);
            }
        }
```

So, it doesn't seem that simple process that I have thought at the beginning. It shows that FARegister and FABookHistory are linked as well.

So, I would really appreciate it if I know what is the proper steps to follow to make sure that not only I get the Fixed Assets back without breaking any relation to other tables but also properly link back to my custom fields and table.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you have to delete them and then put them back in. 
 It would seem like you would want to just cycle through them and update any relevant data.  I'm not our local expert on them, but it sounds like an import scenario would be the simplest way to apply updates or import the records back in if you really must export them, delete them and then re-enter them.

Comment: Didn't see any export option in Fixed Assets Screen (FA3030PL) which we can process and later import back.

Comment: There are many other related tables such as FADetails, FABookBalance, FALocationHistory, etc. I wouldn't recommend you to manually delete anything in the database because you may get data consistency problems after that. Please clarify why do you need to delete fixed assets? What do you wanna get as a result?

Comment: Actually, I also do not know the real reason behind deleting the records and putting them back as that's what my client would do.
My job was to make sure that the data are consistent along with the custom fields and custom child table when they are imported back.

Comment: On a side note, I thought of using Data Export By Scenario, but that also doesn't look like an easy way and really hard to build template (I was thinking of using Excel Provider) for Data Provider.